# Bootstrap input-groups display error in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

Developing a website, I encountered the following problem: in the login panel, the input groups are displayed correctly in chrome and other browsers like safari opera etc.. but not in safari. Here the images that show the differences.

Chrome:

[image]

Safari:

[image]

Here also the html code:

```html
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" required="required"> 
                </div>

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required="required"> 
                </div>
```

I already tried to delete the css file I created (style.css) but nothing changed so i think it must be something related with bootstrap. Anyone knows a solution to this problem?

**EDIT:**

I tried to load the page on Safari on another windows pc and the error was still the same. After I tried to load the page on safari on a Mac and everything seemed to be ok. So the error should be in the windows version of safari

Comment: can you reproduce it on http://www.bootply.com/new ? I copy / paste your html code but i can't reproduce your issue on safari. Can you tell what is the computed style applied to your input ?

Comment: Sorry for my english, but What do you mean with the last question? I reproduced it on bootply and the result is the same! Here the image http://oi57.tinypic.com/ftpw3.jpg

Comment: see edit, maybe it is a problem of safari for windows! You also tried on safari for windows?

Comment: I think Safari for Windows is version 5 still... So maybe you can ignore it, because it is rarely used. If not, give me a hint ;)

Comment: I can confirm this issue, latest version of Safari 5.1.7 for Windows system.

Answer (score -1):

you can fix the height whith css :

```
.input-group-sm>.input-group-addon {
    height: 18px;
}
```

If you import the bootstrap css before your custom style use !important for rewrite the height

```
.input-group-sm>.input-group-addon {
    height: 18px !important;
}
```